# How to print the output in different colums of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to print the output of my program in different columns of a `csv` file. The actual output is shown in only one cell in the `csv` file opened with excel software. Moreover, the numeric result appears wrapped by square brackets (I do not want that). I want to plot my results in different cells, one beside each other. For instance,  1st cell 'text', 2nd cell 'number', 3rd cell 'text'.

I tried different delimeter, like ' ', ',', but no success.

```
import numpy as np 
# DATA
width=0.66  

# WRITING  THE DATA
wii=np.empty([1,1])[0] 
wii[0]=round(width,3)
Width=[['Width' +str(wii)+ ' [m]']]

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:       

    thewriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',') 
    thewriter.writerows(Width)
```

My expected result would be the following one:
Width  0.66 [m]  ('Width, 0.66 and [m] located in three different cells, respectively')

Instead, I get:

Width [0.66] [m] ('Where, Width, [0.66] and [m] are located in the same cell')

How would it be possible to solve this issue?

Comment: I believe you want your `Width` variable to be a list of strings instead of a list. e.g. `[ 'Width', str(wii), '[m]']`

Comment: you can make `Width =f'{variable one},{variable 2},{variable3}'` directly, no real real need to use the csv writer imo

Comment: Hi Killjoy,  I tried your method and I got the results on 3 lines. Each character was located in a single cell. I just want 3 cells. the number 0.66 was still wrapped by square brackets. Her you can find the output: W i d t h 
[ 0 . 6 6 ]
  [ m ]

Comment: Can you please post your entire script and the data you are working with? For example, where does glass come from?

Comment: # DATA
width=0.66  

# WRITING  THE DATA
wii=np.empty([1,1])[0] 
wii[0]=round(width,3)
Width=[['Width' +str(wii)+ ' [m]']]

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:       

    thewriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',') 
    thewriter.writerows(Width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, a few things needed to change:

1. You were printing the `wii` list, not object, so you would always have square brackets. I have fixed that.
2. `writerow` will always put things into different cells, so I changed that to `write`
3. I added in comments to help you understand what I did.

The following script outputs:

[image]

```
import numpy as np 
import csv
#DATA
width=0.66  

#WRITING THE DATA
wii=np.empty([1,1])[0] 
wii[0]=round(width,3)
#print(wii[0]) prints 0.66 no bracket
#Width=['Width' +str(wii)+ 'm'] <- OP old
Width = ["Width", str(wii[0]), "[m]"] # <- NEW

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_Reader:
    # Change from writerow
    csv_Reader.write(",".join(Width))
```

Comment: Hi jerry,in this way i will get the following output.

Comment: W i d t h [ 0 . 6 6 ]   [ m ]

Comment: each single character is located in one cell of excell file, on top of that the square brackets are still there

Comment: Do you want everything in one cell?

Comment: Hi Jerry I want in 3 cells:

Comment: the word width in one cell, the number 0.66 in one cell (NOT wrapped by square brackets ) and the word [m] in the third cell.

Comment: @chrisis please see the new answer

Comment: Hi thanksa gain I found anohter solution, which is much simpler. just Width = [('Width', width, '[m]')] and then thewriter.writerows(Width). It works fine. Also your solution works. thansk again!!